# Java infinite while loop, specific program question

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that creates a menu and lets the user pick an option. The while loop in my getValidChoice method is not functioning as it should. It is an infinite loop, please help! New to Java! Ask questions for clarity!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Main
{
 public static String createMenu(String[] listOfChoices, String menuTitle) {
     String bigStr = menuTitle + "\n\n";
     int count = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < listOfChoices.length; i++) {
         String littleStr = count + ". " + listOfChoices[i] + "\n";
         count = count + 1;
         bigStr = bigStr + littleStr;
     }
     return bigStr;
 }

 public static int getValidChoice(int numChoices, String menu) {
     System.out.println(menu);
     boolean error = true;
     Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
     String number = choice.next();
     char[] inputArray = new char[number.length()];
     for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
         inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
         if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])) {
             error = false;
         }
     }
         while (error == true || (Float.valueOf(number) > numChoices && Float.valueOf(number) < 1)) {
             System.out.println("Invalid choice -- please try again\n");
             System.out.println(menu);
             choice = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
             number = choice.next();
             inputArray = new char[number.length()];
             for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
                 inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
                 if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])) {
                     error = false;
                 }
             }
     }
     return Integer.valueOf(number);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] employeeList = new String[50];
     String[] chList = {"Add New Employee", "Delete Employee", "Change Employee Name", "Print Employee Roster", "Quit"};
     String menuStr = createMenu(chList, "Main Menu");
     int ch = getValidChoice(chList.length, menuStr);
     System.out.println(ch);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
for (int i = 0; i > number.length(); i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
```

Since your `for` loop counter (i.e. `i`) is increasing by `1` with each iteration, it will eventually become equal to `number.length()` and the loop will terminate if we put the condition as `i < number.length()`. In your code, the check fails for the first time itself.

Note that you need to make this change at two places, outside the `while` loop and also inside the `while` loop. Given below is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static String createMenu(String[] listOfChoices, String menuTitle) {
        String bigStr = menuTitle + "\n\n";
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfChoices.length; i++) {
            String littleStr = count + ". " + listOfChoices[i] + "\n";
            count = count + 1;
            bigStr = bigStr + littleStr;
        }
        return bigStr;
    }

    public static int getValidChoice(int numChoices, String menu) {
        System.out.println(menu);
        boolean error = true;
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        String number = choice.next();
        char[] inputArray = new char[number.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])) {
                error = false;
            }
        }
        while (error == true || Float.valueOf(number) > numChoices || Float.valueOf(number) < 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice -- please try again\n");
            System.out.println(menu);
            choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            number = choice.next();
            inputArray = new char[number.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
                inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])) {
                    error = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] chList = { "Add New Employee", "Delete Employee", "Change Employee Name", "Print Employee Roster",
                "Quit" };
        String menuStr = createMenu(chList, "Main Menu");
        int ch = getValidChoice(chList.length, menuStr);
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

A sample run:

```
Main Menu

1. Add New Employee
2. Delete Employee
3. Change Employee Name
4. Print Employee Roster
5. Quit

Enter your choice: a
Invalid choice -- please try again

Main Menu

1. Add New Employee
2. Delete Employee
3. Change Employee Name
4. Print Employee Roster
5. Quit

Enter your choice: 6
Invalid choice -- please try again

Main Menu

1. Add New Employee
2. Delete Employee
3. Change Employee Name
4. Print Employee Roster
5. Quit

Enter your choice: -1
Invalid choice -- please try again

Main Menu

1. Add New Employee
2. Delete Employee
3. Change Employee Name
4. Print Employee Roster
5. Quit

Enter your choice: 3
3
```

Comment: The OP's code has another loop `for (int i = 0; i < listOfChoices.length; i++)` which is correctly written, so this was probably a simple typo, not a misconception.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! When I did that, it worked but it also allowed other inputs that it's not supposed to. Valid input is only 1-5, but it allows me to input 6 instead of going through the loop.

Comment: You are most welcome. You need to make this change at two places, outside the `while` loop and also inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I did, but it's still giving me the same issue.

Comment: I have just posted the code with this correction and I have also posted a sample run. Let me know if you still have a doubt.

Comment: Oh no, the code I put up wasn't the current code I was working with. I changed it as you said, and you're correct. Now my issue is that I can't input letters. I'll update my code.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the code I'm working with and the changes you suggested.

Comment: `Now my issue is that I can't input letters.` - which letter do you want to input? Your program is supposed to accept only a choice from 1 to 5. On entering a letter (e.g. `a`), it should show the error, `Invalid choice -- please try again`. Isn't it?

Comment: Initially yes. Once inside the loop, it throws an error. Sorry, I'm bad at explaining. My professor wants to be able to input anything, but have it redirect the user to enter an integer 1-5.

Comment: Did you check the sample run I have posted in my answer? The corrected code which I have posted in the answer is already behaving in this manner i.e. whenever the user enters a wrong choice (e.g. `a` or `6` or `-1`), the program is redirecting the user to input the right choice. The program terminates only when the right choice is entered. Do you want the program to behave differently?

Comment: That's so weird, it wasn't working when I compiled it. It works now.. sorry! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This change in `getValidChoice()` will fix the problem. Start with `boolean error = false;` instead of `boolean error = true;`.

Starting of the changed method:

```
public static int getValidChoice(int numChoices, String menu) {
    System.out.println(menu);
    boolean error = false; //THIS IS THE CHANGE
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
```

### Edit: Added the changed method

The places where changes have been made are commented with "CHANGE".

```
public static int getValidChoice(int numChoices, String menu) {
    System.out.println(menu);
    boolean error = false;
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    String number = choice.next();
    char[] inputArray = new char[number.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) { //CHANGE: '<' and not '>'
        inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
        if ( !Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])){ //CHANGE: Notice '!'
            error = true; //CHANGE: Error: The character is not a digit.
        } 
    }
        while (error == true || Float.valueOf(number) > numChoices || Float.valueOf(number) < 1) {
            error = false; //CHANGE: Reset error back to false.
            System.out.println("Invalid choice -- please try again\n");
            System.out.println(menu);
            choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            number = choice.next();
            inputArray = new char[number.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i > number.length(); i++) {
                inputArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i])) {
                    error = false;
                }
            }
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(number);
}
```

---

Comment: How do I fix  ``if (Character.isDigit(inputArray[i]))`` since that should make the value true if I'm understanding your solution correctly.

Comment: Frankly, I didn't get the point of that ```for``` loop. (Sorry!) If the whole idea is to check if the entered value is an integer, then it is better to simply call ```Integer.parseInt()``` and handle ```NumberFormatException```. Then, if it fails, set ```error = true```, instead of the current ```error = false```.

Comment: @RonniChristine I have added the whole changed method for your reference. The changed places have been marked. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification. I'm very, very new to Java, sorry for the inefficient code! It still lets me input numbers that it shouldn't, however.